# Cholesky factorisation, I don't understand the following result

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

I have to do the Cholesky factorization of the following matrix :
$A = \begin{pmatrix}
14 & 23 & 18\\ 
23 & 41 & 30\\ 
18 & 30 & 36
\end{pmatrix}$.

I found $A = LL^T = \begin{pmatrix}
\sqrt{14} & 0& 0\\ 
23/\sqrt{14} & 3\sqrt{5}/\sqrt{14}& 0\\ 
18/\sqrt{14} & \sqrt{14}/7\sqrt{5} & 8/\sqrt{5}
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
\sqrt{14} & 23/\sqrt{14}& 18/\sqrt{14}\\ 
0 & 3\sqrt{5}/\sqrt{14}& \sqrt{14}/7\sqrt{5}\\ 
0 & 0 & 8/\sqrt{5}
\end{pmatrix}$.

And on a correction, they found : $A = LL^T = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3\\ 
0 & 4 & 5\\ 
0 & 0 & 6
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\ 
2 & 4 & 0\\ 
3 & 5 & 6
\end{pmatrix}$.

I really don't understand their answer... Someone could explain to me ? Thank you in advance...

Comment: $LL^T\neq A$ for second factorization.

Comment: Sorry :/ I reversed the two matrix, I corrected! But I don't understand how they find this result ...

Comment: I guess we need to factorize $A$ as $UU^T$ instead of $LL^T$.

Comment: How to do it ? I don't know this method... :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$\begin{pmatrix}
14 & 23 & 18\\ 
23 & 41 & 30\\ 
18 & 30 & 36
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13}\\ 
0 & a_{22} & a_{23}\\ 
0 & 0 & a_{33}
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & 0 & 0\\ 
a_{12} & a_{22} & 0\\ 
a_{13} & a_{23} & a_{33}
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} a_{11}^2+a_{12}^2+a_{13}^2 & a_{12}a_{22}+a_{13}a_{23} &a_{13}a_{33}\\
 a_{12}a_{22}+a_{13}a_{23} &a_{22}^2+a_{33}^2 & a_{23}a_{33}\\
a_{33}a_{13} & a_{33}a_{23} & a_{33}^2\end{pmatrix}$$

Now start comparing the matrices elementwise beginning from the last column.